# Which active movements in philosophy today might be aligned with "continental" interests?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, continental-philosophy

Which active movements in philosophy today might be considered allied or aligned with "continental" interests? (Related to [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7605/what-were-the-most-significant-historical-influences-of-continental-philosophy#question).)

Answer (score 2):

Anything with "post-" in the title will be considered "continental". Speculative Realism or Object-Oriented Ontology is also a "continental" approach. This is true even though the practitioners of both are found in North America as well as in Europe; the "continental" term has increasingly lost its geographic referent.